# Repeating Salesforce Workflow actions every x days

Tags: salesforce, workflow, salesforce-lightning

I am a salesforce administrator and I am told to create a new task every 90 days based on a date.

I have created a workflow rule which creates a new task 90 days after the data filed (Initial bill date 2 in my case).

The data field I am based on is a formula field. I tried to update the filed with a field Update action by adding 90 (Initial Bill Date 2 + 90) but I read Workflow rules considerations:

- Field updates occur before email alerts, tasks, and outbound messages.
  -Read-only fields like formula or auto-number fields are not available for field update action.

Until now I have created a workflow rule that triggers a Time dependent new task 90 days after initial bill date 2. I am not finding a way how to repeat this action every 90 days.

Can someone help with an answer? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Time Dependent actions in Workflow Rules and Process Builder do not repeat. They're enqueued exactly once by the platform for each qualifying invocation of the Workflow or Process. That is, the record is modified; it matches the entry criteria of the Workflow; and only then is a single time-dependent action enqueued.

You can sometimes contrive chains of declarative automations to update records in such a way as to cause reevaluation of Workflow criteria and get those actions re-scheduled. However, this is tricky, hard to reason about, and error-prone. Plus, the limit for processing time-dependent actions is only 1,000 per hour, which is really easy to blow past if you're using the feature heavily.

Instead, consider using an app like Doug Ayers' open source [Mass Action Scheduler](https://douglascayers-org.github.io/sfdx-mass-action-scheduler/) to process specific actions on a schedule.

Comment: Thank you David, your answer helped me to clear some thoughts I had on Workflow Rules and Process Builder.

Comment: I just found the solution for repeating tasks with workflow rules. Here are the steps: 

1. Created a workflow rule with an immediate action (create a new task) if a formula evaluates to true. (Formula: Today() - Initial_Bill_Date__c = 45, true, false). 
2. Created a new field "Task date" of type date which will help to re-evaluate the creation of repeating a task.

Comment: 3. Created another workflow rule:  if the formula (Today()- Initial_Bill_Date = 90, true, false) evaluates to true create a task and updates the new created field "Task Date" with Today() + 90. I made sure to select re-evaluate workflow rule after the field changes checkbox. 
4. After that, I created another workflow rule which creates a time-dependent action (new task) 0 days after created field and updates the "Task Date" field again with Today()+90.  I made sure to select re-evaluate workflow rule after the field changes checkbox for this action.